# Java peek next element in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, queue, producer-consumer

I have a `hashmap` with a queue object and I want to peek different objects in the different queue in the order they are located in queue each time i peek an object, typically consumer-producer problem;

```
public class MainQueue {

    public static Map<Integer, SingleQueue> list = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public MainQueue() {

    }

    public Map getQueue() {
        return this.list;
    }

    public void addToMainQueue(SendObject sfo) {
        int ohashcode = sfo.hashCode();
        if (!list.containsKey(ohashcode)) {
            list.put(ohashcode, new SingleQueue());
            list.get(ohashcode).addQueue(sfo);
        } else {
            list.get(ohashcode).addQueue(sfo);
        }

    }

    public SendObject getFromQueue() {

        ???
        return TempFax;
    }
}

---------HashMap-------------

423532,queue1:{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

564898,queue2:{a,b,c,d,e}

039894,queue3:{x,y,z}
```

When I call getFromQueue function, it should return '1'
after I call, return 'a'
after I call, return 'x'

```
finally= 1,a,x,2,b,y,3,c,z,4,d,5,e,6,7,8,9
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question.

Comment: As a side note, you probably shouldn't use hash codes as a key... Two objects can have the same hash code. Generally the point of a hash map is to have e.g. a `Map<SendObject, SingleQueue>`.

Comment: Hash codes are unique key of the queues in the Hashmap. All objects located in these queues.

Comment: HashMaps don't have a 'next element'. You should be using the object itself as the key, not its hashcode. Your question so far doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question you are interested in retrieving those elements in a FIFO order and you need some way to group them into hashcodes.

I suggest adding those SendObject into a single queue like LinkedList<SendObject>, this way you can poll() those elements one by one.

If you need to have some way to group different items into categories (or hashcodes in your case), you can add a Category field for example in SendObject so you can keep track of those.

Comment: HashMap contains thousands SingleQueue, dequeue and enqueue happens same time for each queue. I have to pick queue's first object orderly. Every time another queue's first object.